# How to remove checkbox state on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the following code there are three questions with some checkboxes. There is only one form and the questions change content based on a count state. The values of the chosen checkboxes is saved and displayed in another component.
When I click on the next button I would like to get the new question and the checkboxes to reset. Currently if I check one of the checkboxes and click next, the checkbox still remains checked for the next question. Is it possible to remove the checked state on button click in this scenario?

````
import React from "react";
import questionsData from "../questions-data";


function AddQuestions({ onAddTwo }) {
  const [userinfo, setUserInfo] = React.useState({
    options: [],
    response: [],
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // Destructuring

    const { value, checked } = e.target;
    const { options } = userinfo;

    checked === true
      ? setUserInfo({
          options: [...options, value],
          response: [...options, value],
        })
      : setUserInfo({
          options: options.filter((e) => e !== value),
          response: options.filter((e) => e !== value),
        });
  };
  ///submits to list
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);


  const data = questionsData.data.option;
  const ask = data[count].ask;
  const one = data[count].one;
  const two = data[count].two;
  const three = data[count].three;

  const onSubmitTwo = (e) => { 
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked")
    const daas = userinfo.response;
   !daas.length ? console.log("empty") : onAddTwo({ daas });
   !daas.length ? alert("please add task") : setCount(count + 1);
  };
  //button func
  const stylesNext = {
    display: count > 2 ? "none" : " ",
  };
 
 

  return (
    <>
       <form>
        <div className="one">
        <legend>{ask}</legend>
        <input className= "check--input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    name= "option"
                    value={one}
                    checked ={choice}
                    onChange={handleChange} />
                    <label htmlFor="check--input">{one}</label>

        <input className="check--input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="option"
                    value={two}
                    onChange={handleChange} />
                    <label htmlFor="check--input">{two}</label>
        
        <input className="check--input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="option"
                    value={three}
                    onChange={handleChange} />
                    <label htmlFor="check--input">{three}</label>
        </div>
       <div className="control--btns">
            <button className="next--btn" onClick={onSubmitTwo} style={stylesNext}>
              {count === 2 ? "Submit" : "Next"}
            </button>
          </div>
       </form>
  );
}

export default AddQuestions;
       ```
````

Comment: can't write code now but it happened once with me and issue was the repitition of name or id fields. Try giving all your inputs unique attributes as currently you have same 'name' for all and same for labels' 'htmlFor' attribute.
If that doesn't help, try giving each input unique ID attribute.(checkID1, checkID2 etc)

Comment: the id's and all attributes change(class, value, name  but the checked attribute remains the same , probably because it is saved in state as checked. On button click the attributes change but I also want to remove the checked status, since I get a new set of values.

Comment: A way would be to generate all mcqs as the number of questions..(Map on all questions)...Then show how many per page you want to show. Also add id fields on all MCQ question objects(Considering questions are array of objects) and use those ids as <input name=`name_${question.id}` /> (Unique names).
This way each MCQ will have its own unique state and won't make issues on different pages.